# Does T-Mobile charge international roaming fees in the US Virgin Islands on a US pre-paid plan?

Tags: cellphones, us-virgin-islands

I have an iPhone with T-Mobile Prepaid service.  I am still unclear whether or not I will be charged roaming fees when I am in the United States Virgin Islands.

I tried calling T-Mobile support, but the representative would only say when I am travelling internationally there is a roaming charge, and that there would be no data plan available outside the United States.

When I tried to clarify if the US Virgin Islands were outside the United States, she said they are but her English was such that I wasn't convinced she really understood my question.  I also found several references to T-Mobile having dropped all international roaming charges, casting further doubt on the representative.

So, I return to my original question: Does T-Mobile charge international roaming fees in the US Virgin Islands on a US pre-paid plan?

Comment: T-Mobile dropped international roaming charges on their "Simple Choice" plans, but some sites leave out that detail. I don't think this applies to prepaid plans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [list of international roaming charges](http://tmo-assets-1524598101.netdna-ssl.com/prepaid-phones/pdf/IntlCallingRates.pdf) the Virgin Islands are not listed separately - since they're US territory it is then safe to assume you won't pay roaming.

Comment: oh, and although that list does not seem to come from an official URL, it is linked on the [official TMobile USA prepaid site](http://prepaid-phones.t-mobile.com/prepaid-additional-services).

Answer (score 2):

You will have no issues at all using your T-Mobile phone in the US Virgin islands.  There are no roaming charges or fees.

However, if you hop over to the British Virgin islands you will enter into another country and the the new T-Mobile affiliate network will activate.  If you have the Anywhere plan (the one where you have unlimited text, calls and internet), you will be able to access internet and texts for free but your phone calls will cost 20 cents a minute.

Comment: T-Mobile only offer free data and text roaming on their Pay Monthly (or Postpaid plans).

Comment: Also, you must make sure that your phone is not pinging the BVI towers.  Phones search for the closest cell towers, and often on the islands, phones will select the "wrong" country's towers.  Turn off international roaming on your phone to stop that from happening