# What SIM card/roaming options do I have in the Cayman Islands?

Tags: cellphones, cayman-islands

I will be traveling to the Cayman Islands next year from the US where I use a pre-paid T-Mobile (unlocked, original Motorola RAZR) phone. From the answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35231/does-t-mobile-charge-international-roaming-fees-in-the-us-virgin-islands-on-a-us) about T-Mobile in the US Virgin Islands it appears from the [T-Mobile International Roaming Charges](http://tmo-assets-1524598101.netdna-ssl.com/prepaid-phones/pdf/IntlCallingRates.pdf) I could roam the Caymans for $2.39/minute.

What cheaper options for voice/text would be available for me in the Cayman Islands?

Comment: Google Fi has great international rates in a long list of countries, but you'd need to get a new phone to get Fi service.

Comment: Since your phone's unlocked, if you're planning on using it, it's almost always most economical to buy a local pay-as-you-go/pre-paid SIM card. I've not been to the Cayman Islands (hence this is just a comment) but you'd expect that for somewhere like that the top networks to have shops in the main international airport arrivals area where you can get cheap tourist-friendly deals - a quick google suggests at least one network (LIME) does this, and there seem to be several to choose between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Came, I Saw, I Enjoyed<sup>1</sup>

There are 2 main companies on Grand Cayman that offer pre-paid SIM cards.

1. [Flow](https://discoverflow.ky)
2. [Digicel](https://www.digicelgroup.com/ky/en/mobile.html)

Each of these companies have stores all over the place.

On a random basis I went with Flow and paid $KYD12 ($US16) for a SIM card with $KYD10 of credit, and was in and out of the store in under 5 minutes.  Good service all over the island, but I suffered receiving 1 or 2 text messages every day pushing various deals for topping up the SIM.

In the end I actually only made 1 phone call with the Flow SIM and in hindsight it would have actually have been cheaper to use my pre-paid T-Mobile roaming.  However YMMV.

---

<sup>1. And suffered major sticker shock from food prices</sup>