# Is there any need to rent an SUV on Grand Cayman Island?

Tags: car-rentals, off-road, cayman-islands

As per my [cell phone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83400/what-cell-phone-options-do-i-have-in-the-cayman-islands) question I will be on Grand Cayman Island next year for vacation.  I will be renting a car while I am there, but is there any reason to rent something like a Jeep as opposed to renting a normal sedan.  Or in other words is there anywhere on the island that I'd want to go as a tourist where having a sedan would stop me?

Or is being able to put the top down the only benefit of a Jeep?

Comment: No need for a jeep, just a "cool" thing for tourists to rent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Came, I Saw, I Enjoyed<sup>1</sup>

The roads on Grand Cayman are excellent with the usual smattering of potholes.  This also includes the dirt roads in and around Barker's National Park area.

So no need to rent a 4WD.

---

<sup>1. And suffered major sticker shock from food prices</sup>